# "Deauthorize" user from ActionFilterAttribute specifically

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, authorization, custom-attributes, action-filter

I'm dealing with a scenario whereby I check record ownership with an `ActionFilterAttribute` in a way that requires I pass through the model type the action is dealing with as well as an id parameter, like this:

```
[CheckOwnership(objectId = "clientid", Model = typeof(Client))]
```

and then run a check to see if the user's companyId matches the record's companyId, like this:

```
public class CheckOwnership : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public string objectId { get; set; }
    public object Model { get; set; }
    private MyDatabaseContext db = new MyDatabaseContext();

    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        if (filterContext.ActionParameters.ContainsKey(objectId))
        {
            var id = filterContext.ActionParameters[objectId] as Int32?;
            var model = Model;
            if (model.GetType() == typeof(Client))
            {
                var companyId = SharedLogic.GetCurrentCompanyId();
                var clientCompanyId = db.Clients.Find(id).CompanyId;
                if (companyId != clientCompanyId)
                {
                    // deauthorize user
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**The issues lies in "deauthorizing" the user if they don't own that record in the same fashion as the `[Authorize]` attribute does, by returning the user to the login page.**

The only way I know how to do this is to build a custom `AuthorizeAttribute`but this doesn't allow me to access the id parameter that is passed to the method when the user makes the request. By using `ActionFilterAttribute` I get access to the ActionExecutingContext which I can use to retrieve parameters etc.

Is there a way to deauthorize the user and return them to the login page without using the authorize attribute?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You **should** use `AuthorizeAttribute` and not a `ActionFilterAttribute`.
The reason that you can't access model is that authorization runs before model binder so the model does not exist when attiribute's `OnAuthorization` method is executed. But yo can access all the model properties that passed to the server in `OnAuthorization` method like this:

```
public override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
{
    var rawid = filterContext.Controller.ValueProvider.GetValue("id"); 
    if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(rawid.AttemptedValue))
    {
        int id = rawid.ConvertTo(typeof(int))           
    }

    // in case that user is unauthorized:
    filterContext.Result = new HttpUnauthorizedResult();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your post. I'm just struggling now to convert the value of id to something I can use, trying to convert it to an int of some sort is failing with everything I try.

Comment: What exception are you getting? Check in debugger that id is not null.   You can check that `filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Params["id"]` is there. I don't know how are you trying to convert it to int but this is the way to do it: `id.ConvertTo(typeof(int))`

Comment: I was able to do a conversion using id.AttemptedValue. I'm going to accept this as my answer. You should edit it to include                         filterContext.Result = new HttpUnauthorizedResult();
                        return; though.